# CORS Failed & NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI

Tags: angular, spring-boot, kubernetes, cors

I have an angular application which I am trying to connect to springboot backend but I am getting CORS Failed.
Here's my `angular-deployment.yml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: angular-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: angular
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: angular
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: angular
          image: dockerimage
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: angular-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: angular
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort
```

Here's my springboot-deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot-mysql
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springboot-mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: springboot-k8s
          image: spring-docker-image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom :
                configMapKeyRef :
                  name : db-config
                  key :  host

            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom :
                configMapKeyRef :
                  name : db-config
                  key :  dbName

            - name: DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom :
                secretKeyRef :
                  name : mysql-secrets
                  key :  username

            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom :
                secretKeyRef :
                  name : mysql-secrets
                  key :  password

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: springboot-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: springboot-mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
```

I am using Minikube and I have CORS enabled in kube-apiserver but I am not sure what else I am doing wrong. I would appreciate some help on how to get my angular app to connect to spring. I would also appreciate if someone could tell me if it's an issue from my side or from the angular side.

Comment: either add proper CORS enabling headers to your spring app, or expose both FE and BE on the same host:port (right now you are using 80 and 8080)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. The application doesn't even launch (I changed it to 8080)

Comment: @Antoniossss is right. Either you add proper CORS configurations inside the code of your spring boot app, or you try to serve both from the same port. For example, you can create an ingress and reroute all the requests that contain `*/api/*` to your backend, and the ones that don't have this path segment should be handled by the frontend.

Comment: @darkdead if you just changed both 80 and 8080 to some X port it will obviously not work. It requires routing configuration.

Comment: I see. I know this is dumb but I am still learning so please bear with me. I have talked to the developers who built the app and they said they had fixed the CORS issue by adding proper config. So I guess it's from my end. Is there a beginner friendly guide on adding /using ingress?

Comment: What ingress controller are you using? You can check it by running `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep ingress`. Are you using a cloud solution like GKE, AKS, EKS?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I am using nginx-ingrss controller the default addon which comes with Minikube. The issue is, I don't know how to type the yaml for it. I keep getting `no matches for kind "Service" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first`